# How to discover installed software on Computers in Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-active-directory

I want to "scan" and discover installed software on computers. That can be done by using a PowerShell script as this one:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | select Vendor, Name, Version| Out-File Outputfile.txt -Append
```

But instead of doing this manually, I wondered if it's not something Azure could do automatically. Maybe not exactly this script but do Azure have a solution that can scan the end-user's computer for installed software and collect a log in a central place so you can get an overview.

Best regards

Comment: Please check this MS document it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-installed-software

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Policy Guest Configuration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-policy-now-audits-applications-installed-inside-virtual-machines/) allows you to monitor installed applications on Windows VMs by auditing the configurations inside the VMs.

As mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-installed-software) linked by Rahul, you can also use the Azure Automation Change Tracking and Inventory feature to find out which software is installed on both Azure and non-Azure machines. It will provide you with a list with the software that has been found:

[image]

You can also check for this in the Azure Monitor inventory logs or under the Inventory for each individual VM's resource page.